# Hibernate schema validation failaing

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, amazon-aurora

In the following case hibernate schema validation is failing where following table already exists.

Table Defination

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_dn5jasds5r1j3ewo5k3nhwkkq` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Application code :

```
@Bean
    public DatabaseSchemaValidator databaseSchemaValidator() {
        return new DatabaseSchemaValidator();  // replace this with the actual constructor or a factory method if needed
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(DatabaseSchemaValidator schemaValidateService) {
        return (prop -> {
            List<Integrator> integrators = new ArrayList<>();
            integrators.add(schemaValidateService);
            prop.put("hibernate.integrator_provider", (IntegratorProvider) () -> integrators);
        });
    }
```

Schema validation class

```
public class DatabaseSchemaValidator implements Integrator {
    private final ExecutionOptions executionOptions;
    private SchemaValidator schemaValidator;
    private Metadata metadata;

    public DatabaseSchemaValidator() {
        executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getConfigurationValues() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldManageNamespaces() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
                return ExceptionHandlerHaltImpl.INSTANCE;
            }

            @Override
            public SchemaFilter getSchemaFilter() {
                return SchemaFilter.ALL;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void integrate(
        Metadata metadata,
        BootstrapContext bootstrapContext,
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory
    ) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
        var serviceRegistry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry();
        var schemaManagementTool = new HibernateSchemaManagementTool();
        schemaManagementTool.injectServices(serviceRegistry);
        this.schemaValidator = new GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl(schemaManagementTool, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
        SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
    ) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public String validate() {
        try {
            schemaValidator.doValidation(metadata, executionOptions, ContributableMatcher.ALL);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:aws://${AURORA_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${AURORA_MYSQL_DB_PORT:3306}/${AURORA_MYSQL_DATABASE}
spring.datasource.username=${AURORA_MYSQL_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${AURORA_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

After this i am getting following error :

**Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [client_seq]**

full stack trace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [client_seq]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at com.experimentation.Application.main(Application.java:30)
```